# Solution of Poisson's equation with Neumann boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

Consider the Poisson's equation with Neumann boundary condition
\begin{cases}-\Delta u= f, &\text{ on } \Omega\\
\nabla u \cdot n = g &\text{ on } \partial \Omega\\
\end{cases}
If $g=0$, we can apply Lax-Milgram theorem to show the existence of a unique solution in the space $$V=\{u\in H^1(\Omega):\int_{\Omega}u=0\}.$$
Now, consider for $g\neq0$, with compatibility condition $\int_{\Omega}f+\int_{\partial\Omega}g=0$. The weak formulation in $H^1(\Omega)$ is: Find $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that 
$$\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla v=\int_{\Omega}fv+\int_{\partial\Omega}gv, \forall v\in H^1(\Omega).$$  I am trying to use Fredholm's alternative:
Let us define $$B(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+\int_{\Omega}uv.$$
Then by Lax-Milgram theorem there exists a unique solution $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ for $f\in L^2(\Omega), g\in L^2(\partial \Omega)$ to 
$$B(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}fv+\int_{\partial\Omega}gv, \forall v\in H^1(\Omega).$$ Now I do not know how to proceed for Fredholm's alternative.

Comment: Can't it be done with Fredholm alternative?

Comment: @Mattos I couldn't figure out how to use Fredholm's alternative in this case.

Comment: @Arun it is not clear: What are you asking?